# Spring boot form model

Tags: java, spring, web, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I've a number of posts re this issue but non worked.  I have a model class Role of which i am trying to create a new one from an HTML form but i am getting IllegalStateExcepion.  I recreated an example found on the Spring site but also didn't work with same error

The Model:

```
public class Greeting {

private long id;
private String content;

public long getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(long id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getContent() {
    return content;
}

public void setContent(String content) {
    this.content = content;
}
}
```

the controller

```
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;

import com.jamesdecelis.model.Greeting;

@Controller
public class GreetingController {

    @ModelAttribute("greeting")
    @RequestMapping(value = "/api/greeting", method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public String greetingForm( Model model) {

        model.addAttribute("greeting", new Greeting());
        return "newRole";
}

@RequestMapping(value="/api/greeting", method=RequestMethod.POST)
public String greetingSubmit(@ModelAttribute("greeting") Greeting greeting, Model model) {
    model.addAttribute("greeting", greeting);
    return "";
}
```

}

the HTML form

```
 <!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
    <title>Getting Started: Handling Form Submission</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Form</h1>
        <form id="greeting" role="form" action="@{/greeting}" method="post" th:object="${greeting}">
        <p>Id: <input type="text" th:field="*{id}" /></p>

        <p><input type="submit" value="Submit" /> <input type="reset" value="Reset" /></p>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

and this is the error

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name 'greeting' available as request attribute
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.support.BindStatus.<init>(BindStatus.java:144) ~[spring-webmvc-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.spring4.util.FieldUtils.getBindStatusFromParsedExpression(FieldUtils.java:396) ~[thymeleaf-spring4-2.1.4.RELEASE.jar:2.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.spring4.util.FieldUtils.getBindStatus(FieldUtils.java:323) ~[thymeleaf-spring4-2.1.4.RELEASE.jar:2.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.spring4.util.FieldUtils.getBindStatus(FieldUtils.java:289) ~[thymeleaf-spring4-2.1.4.RELEASE.jar:2.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.spring4.processor.attr.AbstractSpringFieldAttrProcessor.processAttribute(AbstractSpringFieldAttrProcessor.java:98) ~[thymeleaf-spring4-2.1.4.RELEASE.jar:2.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.processor.attr.AbstractAttrProcessor.doProcess(AbstractAttrProcessor.java:87) ~[thymeleaf-2.1.4.RELEASE.jar:2.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.processor.AbstractProcessor.process(AbstractProcessor.java:212) ~[thymeleaf-2.1.4.RELEASE.jar:2.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.dom.Node.applyNextProcessor(Node.java:1017) ~[thymeleaf-2.1.4.RELEASE.jar:2.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.dom.Node.processNode(Node.java:972) ~[thymeleaf-2.1.4.RELEASE.jar:2.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.dom.NestableNode.computeNextChild(NestableNode.java:695) ~[thymeleaf-2.1.4.RELEASE.jar:2.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.dom.NestableNode.doAdditionalProcess(NestableNode.java:668) ~[thymeleaf-2.1.4.RELEASE.jar:2.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.dom.Node.processNode(Node.java:990) ~[thymeleaf-2.1.4.RELEASE.jar:2.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.dom.NestableNode.computeNextChild(NestableNode.java:695) ~[thymeleaf-2.1.4.RELEASE.jar:2.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.dom.NestableNode.doAdditionalProcess(NestableNode.java:668) ~[thymeleaf-2.1.4.RELEASE.jar:2.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.dom.Node.processNode(Node.java:990) ~[thymeleaf-2.1.4.RELEASE.jar:2.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.dom.NestableNode.computeNextChild(NestableNode.java:695) ~[thymeleaf-2.1.4.RELEASE.jar:2.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.dom.NestableNode.doAdditionalProcess(NestableNode.java:668) ~[thymeleaf-2.1.4.RELEASE.jar:2.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.dom.Node.processNode(Node.java:990) ~[thymeleaf-2.1.4.RELEASE.jar:2.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.dom.NestableNode.computeNextChild(NestableNode.java:695) ~[thymeleaf-2.1.4.RELEASE.jar:2.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.dom.NestableNode.doAdditionalProcess(NestableNode.java:668) ~[thymeleaf-2.1.4.RELEASE.jar:2.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.dom.Node.processNode(Node.java:990) ~[thymeleaf-2.1.4.RELEASE.jar:2.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.dom.NestableNode.computeNextChild(NestableNode.java:695) ~[thymeleaf-2.1.4.RELEASE.jar:2.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.dom.NestableNode.doAdditionalProcess(NestableNode.java:668) ~[thymeleaf-2.1.4.RELEASE.jar:2.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.dom.Node.processNode(Node.java:990) ~[thymeleaf-2.1.4.RELEASE.jar:2.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.dom.Document.process(Document.java:93) ~[thymeleaf-2.1.4.RELEASE.jar:2.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.TemplateEngine.process(TemplateEngine.java:1155) ~[thymeleaf-2.1.4.RELEASE.jar:2.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.TemplateEngine.process(TemplateEngine.java:1060) ~[thymeleaf-2.1.4.RELEASE.jar:2.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.TemplateEngine.process(TemplateEngine.java:1011) ~[thymeleaf-2.1.4.RELEASE.jar:2.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.spring4.view.ThymeleafView.renderFragment(ThymeleafView.java:335) ~[thymeleaf-spring4-2.1.4.RELEASE.jar:2.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.spring4.view.ThymeleafView.render(ThymeleafView.java:190) ~[thymeleaf-spring4-2.1.4.RELEASE.jar:2.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1243) ~[spring-webmvc-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processDispatchResult(DispatcherServlet.java:1027) ~[spring-webmvc-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:971) ~[spring-webmvc-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:893) ~[spring-webmvc-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:968) ~[spring-webmvc-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:859) ~[spring-webmvc-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:622) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.32.jar:8.0.32]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:844) ~[spring-webmvc-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.32.jar:8.0.32]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:292) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.32.jar:8.0.32]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.32.jar:8.0.32]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-8.0.32.jar:8.0.32]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.32.jar:8.0.32]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.32.jar:8.0.32]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:316) ~[spring-security-web-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:126) ~[spring-security-web-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:90) ~[spring-security-web-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330) ~[spring-security-web-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:114) ~[spring-security-web-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330) ~[spring-security-web-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:122) ~[spring-security-web-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330) ~[spring-security-web-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:111) ~[spring-security-web-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330) ~[spring-security-web-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:169) ~[spring-security-web-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330) ~[spring-security-web-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:48) ~[spring-security-web-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330) ~[spring-security-web-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:205) ~[spring-security-web-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330) ~[spring-security-web-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:120) ~[spring-security-web-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330) ~[spring-security-web-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.csrf.CsrfFilter.doFilterInternal(CsrfFilter.java:96) ~[spring-security-web-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330) ~[spring-security-web-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:64) ~[spring-security-web-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330) ~[spring-security-web-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:91) ~[spring-security-web-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330) ~[spring-security-web-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:53) ~[spring-security-web-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330) ~[spring-security-web-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:213) ~[spring-security-web-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:176) ~[spring-security-web-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346) ~[spring-web-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:262) ~[spring-web-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.32.jar:8.0.32]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.32.jar:8.0.32]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99) ~[spring-web-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.32.jar:8.0.32]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.32.jar:8.0.32]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HttpPutFormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpPutFormContentFilter.java:87) ~[spring-web-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.32.jar:8.0.32]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.32.jar:8.0.32]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:77) ~[spring-web-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.32.jar:8.0.32]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.32.jar:8.0.32]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:121) ~[spring-web-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.32.jar:8.0.32]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.32.jar:8.0.32]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:212) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.32.jar:8.0.32]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.32.jar:8.0.32]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.32.jar:8.0.32]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:141) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.32.jar:8.0.32]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.32.jar:8.0.32]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.32.jar:8.0.32]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:522) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.32.jar:8.0.32]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1095) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.32.jar:8.0.32]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:672) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.32.jar:8.0.32]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1500) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.32.jar:8.0.32]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1456) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.32.jar:8.0.32]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [na:1.8.0_65]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [na:1.8.0_65]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.32.jar:8.0.32]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_65]
```

Comment: Do you get the error when loading the form? Or when submitting the form?

Comment: When loading the form

Answer (score 3):

I can see some erros in your code.

First of all the controller, you should not have `@ModelAttribute("greeting")` 
on your `@RequestMapping` because otherwise you get an exception. You can use `@ModelAttribute("greeting")`  if you have a method that return an Greeting object. without `@RequestMapping.`

then in your template you should have  `th:action="@{/api/greeting}"` and not  `action="@{/greeting}`" : without th: namespace you cannot benefit of thymeleaf functionality and the url is wrong, in your controller you have /api/greeting for serving the post request.

the post `@RequestMapping` method should return a view name otherwise the method should be void and the page will be the same of the previous get request

The rest is correct I tried it and it works.

I hope that it can help you

Answer (score 1):

The error that catches means what you haven't set **BindingResult** for your form's backing bean. **NOTE** that it must be set **straight after** your `Greeting` model attribute.

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Neither BindingResult nor plain
>   target object for bean name 'greeting' available as request attribute

Set it in the `POST` method :

```
@RequestMapping(value="/api/greeting", method=RequestMethod.POST)
public String greetingSubmit(
    @ModelAttribute("greeting") Greeting greeting, 
    BindingResult bindingResult, 
    Model model) {
        if (bindingResult.hasErrors) {
            //errors handling  
        }
        model.addAttribute("greeting", greeting);
        return "";
}
```

Comment: amended code but still didn't work.  The error is being produced when i try to load the form :(